# ASP.Net Identity - Implementing two factor authentication using email ONLY

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, two-factor-authentication

I'm currently implementing an MVC5 application which will be hosted on the cloud, and registered users will have to successfully be authenticated in order the access its content. So far the authentication consists of simple email and password login, but due to the sensitive information which the site is to contain,  I'd like to push up the security factor by introducing two factor authentication using email NOT SMS.

I have spent hours looking into ways on how to implement this, but everything leads towards 2-Factor Authentication using SMS or email confirmation, which I don't need. I know this is possible because email confirmation works similarly but only once and not every time the users try and login. Do you have any suggestions?

And while we're at it, is 2-Factor Authentication using SMS that much more secure than Email?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered a token based approach to 2FA where users use apps like [Authy](https://www.authy.com/app/) or [Google Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2&hl=en) to generate a code each time?

Comment: This article http://johnatten.com/2014/04/20/asp-net-identity-2-0-setting-up-account-validation-and-two-factor-authorization/ has both but it seems that it can be changed to implement only email.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368154/how-to-make-google-authentication-scan-qr-code/47368506#47368506 here is something ..